# Server Socket connection Java

Tags: java, serversocket

I have created a server socket with port 4242 but, It is getting timed out. serversock.accept() takes very long time to execute. Please advice.

```
ServerSocket serversock= new ServerSocket(4242);

System.out.println("Waiting " + serversock.getLocalPort() + "...");

Socket socket = serversock.accept();

System.out.println("Just connected to "  + serversock.getLocalSocketAddress());
```

Comment: accept() waits for clients to connect. As long as there are no clients, it will block.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok. You must run it, and then try to connect to your 4242 port in order for your program to proceed to the `println` instruction. `accept()` blocks until a connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/singlethreaded-server.html) how to handle ServerSockets and (Client)Sockets.

There you can see how your problem can be solved by accessing the port 8080 with your browser without another Java programm.